# Rails Action Cable: ArgumentError in MessagesController#create - Wrong Number of Arguments (given 1, expected 2), error in Rails7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, arguments, actioncable

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails application with Action Cable for real-time messaging. I've encountered an error in my MessagesController that I can't seem to resolve. Here are the details:
Error Message:

```
ArgumentError in MessagesController#create
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)
```

MessagesContoller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user

  def create
    message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)

    if message.save
      ActionCable.server.broadcast "chatroom_channel", foo: message.body
    end
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

Additional Information:
•   My ChatroomChannel and JavaScript subscription code (chatroom.js) seem to be correctly set up.
•   I have checked that the channel name matches in both the server and client code.
•   The message_params method is correctly permitting the :body parameter.

```
// app/assets/javascripts/channels/chatroom.js

App.chatroom = App.cable.subscriptions.create("ChatroomChannel", {
  connected: function () {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected: function () {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received: function (data) {
    // Called when the server broadcasts a message to this channel
    // You can handle the received data here, e.g., append the message to the chatroom UI
    console.log(data);
    console.log("Received data:", data);
    $("#message-container").append(data.foo);
  },
});
```

chatroom_channel.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class ChatroomChannel < ActionCable::Channel::Base

    def subscribed

      stream_from "chatroom_channel"
    end

  end
end
```

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?
Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Implicit hash literals (a hash with no brackets). Can only be used to pass a hash as a positional argument if the method does not take keyword arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your message like this:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "chatroom_channel", {foo: message.body}
```

Notice the curly braces.

(https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.0/classes/ActionCable/Server/Broadcasting.html)

Comment: sir the issue is resolved successfully, but i think my connection is not established properly, can you please let  me know the issue too, as i am a beiginer in ror and i do not know how to use action cable smoothly

Comment: Well, that's another question and goes far behind the answers headline ;). You would have to provide much more of your client-side code. There is guide for this here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

Comment: I personally do not use ActionCable but the Turbo-Framework, which builds on Action Cable. Have a look here: https://turbo.hotwired.dev/ - especially Turbo Streams might be helpful.

Comment: @zaphodbln_ I deleted my comment. I missed the fact that it takes a keyword arg which changes it.